# Precipitous ideals and GCH

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, inner-model-theory, gch

It is well known that ZFC + "There is a measurable cardinal" is equiconsistent with ZFC + "There is a precipitous ideal on $\omega_1$."  Is ZFC + "There is a measurable $\kappa$ such that $2^\kappa > \kappa^+$" equiconsistent with ZFC + "There is a precipitous ideal on $\omega_1$" + CH + $2^{\omega_1}>\omega_2$?

Comment: The theory ZFC plus a measurable $\kappa$ with $2^\kappa>\kappa^+$ is equiconsistent with a $\kappa^{++}$-tall cardinal, which is equiconsistent with a $(\kappa+2)$-strong cardinal.

Comment: I'd say that the title is a bit misleading, and should probably be "Precipitous ideals and the *negation* of GCH".

Answer (score 6):

Just a measurable cardinal is sufficient.

Assume $\kappa$ is a measurable cardinal and force with $Col(\omega, < \kappa)*\dot{Add}(\kappa, \tau^*)$, where $\tau^* \geq \kappa^{++}$
is suitably defined (see Gitik's paper ``[On Generic Elementary Embeddings](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=9088265&fileId=S0022481200041438)'').

As it is shown in the above cited paper, there is a nomral precipitous ideal on $\omega_1$ in the resulting generic extension.